# Why Systemd remove my SHM file but not Postgresql's?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, ipc, shared-memory, systemd

I'm developing a daemon application on Ubuntu server that being managed by Systemd.

I create a SHM file in /dev/shm/ by using `shm_open`, and `close` the file descriptor after calling to `mmap`. At the beginning it exists, but it disappeared after a time, maybe as I loged out from the server.

Perhaps this is controlled by the option `RemoveIPC=yes` in /etc/systemd/logind.conf.

My question is

1. Why does systemd not clean up the shm file created by Postgresql, but mine?
2. How to modify my app to make it like Postgresql, so that we can reduce the managing/maintaining work at the producing time.
3. I found that the shm memory is still available after it be cleaned by systemd. Does this mean that I can ignore that, and continue to use it without recreating?

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your suspicion is right; see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/kernel-resources.html#SYSTEMD-REMOVEIPC) for details:

> If systemd is in use, some care must be taken that IPC resources (including shared memory) are not prematurely removed by the operating system. This is especially of concern when installing PostgreSQL from source. Users of distribution packages of PostgreSQL are less likely to be affected, as the `postgres` user is then normally created as a system user.
>
> The setting `RemoveIPC` in `logind.conf` controls whether IPC objects are removed when a user fully logs out. System users are exempt. This setting defaults to on in stock systemd, but some operating system distributions default it to off.
> [...]
>
> A “user logging out” might happen as part of a maintenance job or manually when an administrator logs in as the `postgres` user or something similar, so it is hard to prevent in general.
>
> What is a “system user” is determined at systemd compile time from the `SYS_UID_MAX` setting in `/etc/login.defs`.
>
> Packaging and deployment scripts should be careful to create the `postgres` user as a system user by using `useradd -r`, `adduser --system`, or equivalent.
>
> Alternatively, if the user account was created incorrectly or cannot be changed, it is recommended to set
>
> ```
> RemoveIPC=no
> ```
>
> in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` or another appropriate configuration file.

While this is talking about PostgreSQL, the same applies to your software. So take one of the recommended measures.